# postgresql configuration for gitlab

Tags: database, postgresql, gitlab

Does anybody know how to configure an external postgresql db instance for gitlab by stopping existing postgresql db.
I have configured and getting below error :

```
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

bash[migrate gitlab-rails database] (gitlab::database_migrations line 54) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20191017-5935-1x4dofd" ----
STDOUT: rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "ec2-**_**_**.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com" (172.31.2.73) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:48:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:db:configure
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
STDERR: 
---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20191017-5935-1x4dofd" ----
Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20191017-5935-1x4dofd" returned 1
```